# Drawing shapes using canvas

Tags: javascript, qt, canvas, qml

I use canvas in Qml. How do I draw the following shape using canvas? What else can I do if it is not possible with the canvas? (It will be an animation.)

Start state: [image: Start state]

End state: [image: End State]

Thanks.

Comment: you can simply use GIF images like [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-animatedimage.html)

Comment: You always can paint your item using `QQuickItem`/`QQuickPaintedItem`. What is algorithm of painting this figure?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. There are 180 images.Also the animation will change according to the value entered from outside. Is the gif the correct solution for this issue?

Comment: Each notch will be painted according to the entered speed value.

Comment: There are multiple ways you could do this: multiple images, single images, no images but drawing commands and gradients. I don't think this is a good question, because you're asking for _advice_ on an _approach_, not help with _specific code_. That said, I'd do this by drawing the full image and then covering it with a path of white painted on a canvas using cubic Bézier commands (assuming you don't need transparency).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure to understand what you really want, but I will try to answer.

First, I think you can do it all using `Canvas`. But it is very greedy, so if you do it for embedded devices, you should avoid `Canvas`.
Sorted by efficiency, here's how you can draw complex form :

- [C++] Create class derived from  QQuickItem and override QQuickItem::updatePaintNode()
- [C++] Create class derived from QQuickPaintedItem and override QQuickPaintedItem::paint()
- [QML] Create Canvas-based item

Also, if you have all the images (meaning every step needed for the animation) and have plenty of power, you could use it directly, using [QPixmap](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpixmap.html), [QGraphicsScene](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsscene.html) [C++], or [Images](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-image.html) [QML].

In any case, I advice you to edit you question and ask a more accurate question. (Sorry I can't put this in the comment section my reputation is bellow 50).

Comment: Firstly thank you for your comment. I will try to be more descriptive. This will be a speedometer. There are 180 images about this. The pictures you see above are the 2nd and 180th images. But I think using pictures is a not good method. For this reason I am looking for another method. (PS:These codes will work on apalis-tk1.)

Comment: If you are looking for an other method, with this power, you can use Canvas. But this will be some work. The design is "complex" and the animation will surely be no more than a printing machine.

Comment: What is the best method for you? Would you give a little detail on this?I'm sorry I'm new to QT. Thanks.

Comment: As I only developp apps and tools for embedded devices, to me, neither methods are optimal. So I can't go in much details. Yet, I'll try to developp so you could choose, not surely, but maybe wisely. Qt Quick was made to developp designed application, in a very easy way. Yet, it will take you some time reaching the perfect copy of the picture you shew, if you do. Plus, Canvas uses JavaScript code (sort of), which is very greedy. Your animation seems very complex (design) to me, so if you have all the images avalaible, I would suggest you to try using them first.

Comment: But don't get me wrong, using PixMap is in my mind never a good idea. Someone who uses Qt Quick every day would probably disagree with my previous comment.

Comment: 180 pictures are available for speed, 120 pictures are available for battery.I tried calling the images one by one in response to the entered speed values.But the first build lasted a long time.(About 5 min.) It also seems irrational for me to constantly call for pictures. That's why I started looking for other ways.I still can not find an answer. Thank you for giving a time.